# Shortcut for starting two apps in snap-mode for windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

Snap of apps in windows 8.1 can relatively easily be achieved by dragging and dropping two apps.However, I would like to have shortcut on the start page that automatically brings up two or three apps in "snap-mode".

The input to needs to be something like executable1, executable2, executable3, snap-size1 (% of screen), snap-size2 and snap-size3.

Does such an app exist?

If not, does there exist an API which can be used for this purpose?

Comment: This isn't possible at this time.